# MongoDB Realm SwiftUI continue session / auto login

Tags: mongodb, authentication, swiftui, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I'm using SwiftUI 2 with a MongoDB synced Realm (10.5.2) and I'm currently stuck with how to continue a session once a user reopens the app.

As an authentication I use email and password via a publisher and I know that I can check if the user is logged in with this function:

```
app.currentUser!.isLoggedIn
```

which also returns true for my user. However I don't know how I can get the publisher $0 from the

```
app.login(credentials: .emailPassword(email: username, password: password))
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: {
                self.state.shouldIndicateActivity = false
                switch $0 {
                case .finished:
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    self.state.error = error.localizedDescription
                }
            }, receiveValue: {
                self.state.cardPublisher.send($0)

            })
            .store(in: &state.cancellables)
```

method where I use

```
self.state.cardPublisher.send($0)
```

to fetch my data. So my question is **how do I get the $0 if the user restarts the app.**

Sorry if that's a stupid question but I'm quite new to combine.

Any help is much appreciated :)

If it's helpful for you, I currently have these two publishers:

```
var cardPublisher = PassthroughSubject<RealmSwift.User, Error>()
let cardRealmPublisher = PassthroughSubject<Realm, Error>()
```

which are used like this:

```
cardPublisher
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .flatMap { user -> RealmPublishers.AsyncOpenPublisher in
                self.shouldIndicateActivity = true
                var realmConfig = user.configuration(partitionValue: "teamID=123")
                realmConfig.objectTypes = [Card.self, Dog.self]
                return Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: realmConfig)
            }
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .map {
                self.shouldIndicateActivity = false
                return $0
            }
            .subscribe(cardRealmPublisher)
            .store(in: &self.cancellables)

cardRealmPublisher
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { result in
                if case let .failure(error) = result {
                    self.error = "Failed to log in and open realm: \(error.localizedDescription)"
                }
            }, receiveValue: { realm in
                self.cardRealm = realm
                self.loadData()
            })
            .store(in: &cancellables)
```

Comment: Not sure the question is clear; when a user logs in the first time, you would generally call [Realm.asyncOpen](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/ios/quick-start/#open-a-realm) to make the initial connection to ensure data is fresh. Why wouldn't you do the same thing if the user is already authenticated?

Comment: Hi Jay, I just updated my question. I hope it's now clearer where I need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it myself and it was actually quite easy. For anyone who might need it as well just use this method once the app loads:

```
if app.currentUser!.isLoggedIn {
                app.currentUser.publisher
                .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
                .sink(receiveCompletion: {
                    self.shouldIndicateActivity = false
                    switch $0 {
                    case .finished:
                        break
                    case .failure(let error):
                        self.error = error.localizedDescription
                    }
                }, receiveValue: {
                    self.error = nil
                    self.cardPublisher.send($0)

                })
                .store(in: &self.cancellables)
} else { 
// Regular Login
}
```